# bulk insert by dynamic file name

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, bulk

I try to bulk insert different files.

When i code it like:

```
SET @xml=( Select * From OPENROWSET(
                BULK  'C:\Data\csvToXml.xml',SINGLE_BLOB)x)
```

it is working.

If i take path as parameter like:

```
     SET @Path= 'C:\Data\csvToXml.xml'  


SET @SqlStmt= N' Select @xmlDoc=( Select * From OPENROWSET(
                BULK '''+@Path+''' ,SINGLE_BLOB)x)'

     exec sp_executesql @SqlStmt, N'@xmlDoc XML',@xmlDoc
```

@xmlDoc seems empty. I cannot find where I'm wrong.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What language? I assume you're on Windows from the C:\ ?

Comment: You should add tags for that then

Comment: Ok, i added. Thanks therefromhere.

Comment: not quite what I meant, I've fixed

Answer (score 0):

Came here looking for a solution to my own problem but ended up solving this one!

```
DECLARE @Output int = 0;
DECLARE @params nvarchar(max) = N'@DesiredValue int OUTPUT';
DECLARE @sql_string nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT @DesiredValue = 13';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_string,  @params, @DesiredValue = @Output OUTPUT
SELECT @Output -- yields 13
```

It turns out you need to pass the keyword OUTPUT not only in the @params argument but also on the variables you wish to retrieve. The "@DesiredValue = @Output OUTPUT" looks a little odd because @Output is taking the value of @DesiredValue rather than the other way around.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).